Why re-thrown error from catch block is different then it thrown from try block?
So if we throw a error and there is no try-catch block it will go to the call stack and will be considered as an unhandled exception and which may crash the system.
But when we have the try-catch block then also we re-throw the error from the catch block, then how the second throw is different from the first, and why it will not crash the system like the first one, here is the example code
  @Get(':id')
  async findOne(@Param('id') id: string) {
    try {
      // Code to find cat by ID
      const cat = await this.catService.findOne(id);
      if (!cat) {
        throw new NotFoundException('Cat not found');
      }
      return cat;
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle error
      console.error(error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
}


"how the second throw is different from the first" - it isn't.
